# Change Desktop Wallpaper using a Jpeg file

Tags: c#, windows

I'm trying to write a simple program to change my desktop wallpaper.
I'm using a downloaded jpeg file and I would like to convert it in code.
The problem is the bitmap needs to be 24 bit to display.
How do I do this?
Thanks in advance.

```
public class ChangeWallpaper
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern int SystemParametersInfo(int uAction, int uParam, string lpvParam, int fuWinIni);

    public static void Main()
    {
        Bitmap wallbm = new Bitmap("pic.jpg");
        wallbm.Save("pic.bmp");
        SystemParametersInfo(20, 0, "pic.bmp", 0x01 | 0x02);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is obviously for some version of Windows based on the code, but you might want to clarify that and tag it as such. It'll help someone who's more familiar with this subject matter find and answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't get Clone to work for some reason.
I was able to get it to work by trial and error by using the following code:

```
public class ChangeWallpaper
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern int SystemParametersInfo(int uAction, int uParam, string lpvParam, int fuWinIni);

    public static void Main()
    {
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile("pic.jpg"));
        bm.Save("pic.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
        SystemParametersInfo(20, 0, "pic.bmp", 0x01 | 0x02);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Bitmap.Clone()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141944.aspx) method and specify the desired pixel format.